# jQuery - specific variable value for each element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

I am trying to create an adaptive circle element, that will have the same height as its width, the code is here:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
//Adaptive Circle
var width = jQuery(".circle-adaptive").width();
jQuery(".circle-adaptive").css({"height":width+"px", "line-height":width+"px"});
});
```

It works when I have one set of such circles, but when I create another div with different division:

```
<div class="container" style=" border:2px solid black">
    <div class="container onethird">
        <div class="circle-adaptive red">R</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container onethird">
        <div class="circle-adaptive green">G</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container onethird">
        <div class="circle-adaptive blue">B</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="border:2px solid black">
    <div class="container onequarter">
        <div class="circle-adaptive pink"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container onequarter">
        <div class="circle-adaptive yellow"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container onequarter">
        <div class="circle-adaptive gray"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container onequarter">
        <div class="circle-adaptive magenta"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It does no longer work and the circles keep their height generated in the first case.

Is there a way to make the variable generate once another element is created?

Answer (score 0):

It works. But second container has no texts, so you don't see anything.

```
    <div class="container" style=" border:2px solid black">
        <div class="container onethird">
            <div class="circle-adaptive red">R</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container onethird">
            <div class="circle-adaptive green">G</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container onethird">
            <div class="circle-adaptive blue">B</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="border:2px solid black">
        <div class="container onequarter">
            <div class="circle-adaptive pink">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container onequarter">
            <div class="circle-adaptive yellow">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container onequarter">
            <div class="circle-adaptive gray">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="container onequarter">
            <div class="circle-adaptive magenta"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here tested for you with filled text: (https://jsfiddle.net/L0rf3vam/)

Comment: But these circles are not circels as I expect, they turned into ellipses, because the width saved in the variable was used to create those circles, thus they have smaller width and the same height.